# PowerShell Module Deployment Duplication

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I am using Azure DevOps to deploy PowerShell modules to a server. This release task deploys the modules to the directory `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`. I am able to use the modules once they are deployed to this folder successfully.

If I modify one of the modules and re-release it the file in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\` gets updated, however the old version of the module is still used when running from a batch file using `pwsh`.

I discovered that the module file also exists in the following paths:

- C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules\
- C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\Modules\

When deploying the new version using Azure DevOps the old version in the above two directories are *not* updated. Manually updating the module in those locations fixes the problem.

Why is the module file being copied into those two additional paths?
Should those copies be overwritten when a new version of the module is deployed?
What is the correct way of deploying a module in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell uses different paths to load modules. Use `$env:PSModulePath -split ";"` to know which are the paths being used. 
The difference between each path is user scope and usage scope (e.g. made for custom modules or windows official modules).

Now, by default, **PS looks for the latest version of each module across all the paths**. So maybe the old version is being run because at the time you re-deploy. You are not updating the module version in the Module Manifest, so if PS see they are the "same" version it gets the last one loaded on the PSModulePath.

Take a look at this awesome post for more details: [Everything you wanted to know about PowerShell's Module Path](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/11/11/EverythingYouWantedToKnowAboutPowerShellModulePath/)

Now to your questions.

- Why is the module file being copied into those two additional paths?

  This could be a server configuration or the script that you are using to deploy.
- Should those copies be overwritten when a new version of the module is deployed?

  Not necessarily, if the versions are maintained correctly. On the post shared says how to check the versions of each module.